# Passing user/pwd credentials to (PlaneXML) WSDL service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to access the PlaneXML wsdl service (provides realtime info on flights).

As part of the learning process, I've successfully created a client and connected to an open service for stock price info, and that works great.

The PlaneXML service requires authentication - I have my credentials, but I can't figure out how to offer them up.

I've searched through the client that Eclipse produced from the WSDL but can't find any sign of where to put them.

Can I infer this information from the WSDL file?

```
http://planexml.flightwise.com/ws/PlaneXMLv1.asmx?WSDL
```

Hopefully someone can put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the WSDL for how authentication should be performed but accessing the endpoint of the web service gives back this response header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="fbowebRealm"
```

which makes me think that the access is performed using [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Try with Basic Authentication or pop them an email and just ask.